# Using Composer/Installers for Cakephp, how do I Commit Dependencies in my Plugin Directory?

Tags: git, cakephp, installation, composer-php

I want the best of both worlds: git for master project management and composer for CakePHP plugin management. I understand that this is a very disagreeable topic currently, but for me right now it is the best solution.

I'm using [Composer Installers](https://github.com/composer/installers) for CakePHP. I want to use the setup described in option 4 listed in the Composer FAQs here:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md

Which is quoted here:

> Add a .gitignore rule (vendor/.git) to ignore all the vendor .git
>   folders. This approach does not require that you delete dependencies
>   from disk prior to running a composer update.

Since I'm using the Composer Installers package with CakePHP the packages will therefore be within the "Plugin" folder.

I've tried to add the following to .gitignore so that i can commit plugins to the master project:

```
Plugin/.git
Plugin/**/.git
```

But, alas, git still treats my Composer Installer packages as submodules and will not commit the Plugins to the master project.

It seems like the .gitignore lines above would be all that it would take so i must be missing something to get this setup working, right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen this blog post? http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/07/23/migrating-svn-apps-to-git-and-composer/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `git add . --all` then `git commit --all`?

It seems like you have a new file, usually people will adding it manualli using `git add` but, adding all files in plugin folder would take a lot of time.

Comment: I've tried adding with the --all flag with no luck.

Comment: Just delete that lines then, git will automatically ignore .git folders.

Comment: I've tried that. git still treats them as submodules which is what i do not want.